# Jquery post not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to load data from my local json file with jquery post. but it's not working for me but the same code below works when i replace $.post() to $.ajax(). but i want this with jquery Post only. I am getting (failed)net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND in console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
<script src="jquery-2.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#ajx").click(function(){
        $.post({
            type:"POST",
            dataType:"JSON",
            data:{},
        url: 'ajax_info.json',
        beforeSend:function(){
        alert("before ajax");
        },        
        success:function(data){

            console.log(data);

        },error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }

        });

    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<input type="button" id="ajx" value="Load File Content">


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look at the api at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: type property not available in $.post  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) has a different structure of arguments compared to `$.ajax`, because `$.post` is simply a shortcut without having to specify a type property, so `$.post` and `$.ajax` aren't directly interchangeable.

The closest `$.post` equivalent would be:

```
$.post('ajax_info.json', {}, function(data){
    console.log(data);
}, 'json')
.error(function(){
    // handle erros
});
```

As you can see, `$.post` is not able to set a `beforeSend` handler, so it's not functionally the same as your `$.ajax` version.

Answer (score 0):

Note the correct jquery.post syntax

```
jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] [, dataType ] )
```

see this http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: but i can pass argument in any order.

Comment: because it cannot recognize the url parameter, therefore you get a net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND error

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your $.post method like:

```
 $.post( "ajax_info.json", function( data ) {
  alert("success");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$.post is a shorthand of $.ajax 
You can use it like this

```
$("#ajx").click(function(){
        $.post( "ajax_info.json", function( data ) {
        //success
          console.log(data);
        })
          .done(function() {
            alert( "second success" );
          })
          .fail(function() {
            //error handling here
            alert( "error" );
          })
          .always(function() {
            alert( "finished" );
        });
  });
```